# How to fix Relay unit test throwing error "Invariant violation: graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime"?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, relayjs, ts-jest

I'm using react+relay+jest+typescript and my tests are failing as they are unable to understand graphql. The error thrown is:

```
Error: Uncaught [Invariant violation: graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime.
Either the babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call
site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as `graphql`.]
```

I'm using ts-jest in jest.config. And it is working as expected while running the app. It's while running the tests it is failing.